# systemd: Unknown lvalue 'ExecCondition' in section 'Service

Tags: debian, systemd, debian-stretch

Why `systemd` complains?

```
Jul  5 09:55:33 st701a-9 systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/load-xyz-modules.service:7] Unknown lvalue 'ExecCondition' in section 'Service'
```

The service configuration `/etc/systemd/system/load-xyz-modules.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load xyz kernel modules

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
Type=oneshot
ExecCondition=/bin/sh -c '***'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '***'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '***'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I read the `systemd` [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/systemd/systemd.service.5.en.html) correctly, `ExecCondition` is an option of the section `[Service]`.

**Edit**:
The issue happened on Debian `stretch`.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Oh, I've to mention it indeed. I've faced the issue on Debian stretch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian 9 has systemd 232, which does not include `ExecCondition=`. This was  added in systemd [243](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/aca8ecc39892dda22a1cc0ea6860cbc0774897f3/NEWS#L3250). This means it is also not available in Debian 10, which has only systemd 241. If this functionality is critical, you should choose a different Linux distribution.